# Botón que redireccione con Flask

Tags: html, python, flask

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto y necesito ayuda en como hacer el código para que un botón que he diseñado con HTML y CSS me redireccione a otra página que he creado también. Estoy utilizando Flask con Python. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Monopoly Online.</title>   
        <meta charset = "uft-8">
        <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="/static/CSS/estilos.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img style="width: 1100px;" class="logo1" src="/static/Imagenes/Logo%20Monopoly1.png">
        <input class="boton" type="submit" value="JUGAR" name="jugar" onclick="location.href='/templates/Pagina2.html'">
        <p>Creado por KESTOC </p>
    </body>

</html>
```

Código Python con Flask:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, render_template, flash, session
import sys
import flask
from flask import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_envvar('FLASKR_SETTINGS', silent=True)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def inicio():
    """
    """
    error = None
    return render_template('Inicio_monopoly.html', error=error)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Para poder ayudarte, deberías dejar una porción del código de lo que has intentado, sino es muy complicado darte una respuesta concreta

Comment: Listo ya puse el código tanto de Brackets como de Python, el boton que quiero hacer funcionar de tal manera que mencione es el de JUGAR. Y supongo que solucionando ese, el resto de botones serán similar mente igual. Cabe mencionar que en el codigo de Brackets el boton esta con el location.href y de esa manera me funciona localmente y con la vista previa dinamica del editor, pero la cuestion es que funcione con `Flask`. Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Tienes que tener el servidor flask corriendo en alguna máquina, cuya IP y puerto debes conocer (o bien que tenga un nombre en el DNS). Supongamos que su IP es `180.23.14.42` y el puerto `5000`. Entonces sólo tienes que cambiar el `onclick="location.href='/templates/Pagina2.html'"` de tu HTML por `onclick="location.href='http://180.23.14.42:5000'"`

Comment: Me sirvió, te lo agradezco.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas crear la definición para la **pagina2.html**

```
@app.route('/pagina2')
def pagina2():
    return render_template('pagina2.html')
```

y direccionar tu botón a la ruta:
ya sea

```
 href="/pagina2" o href="{{url_for('pagina2')}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas en la opción onclick del input estas dando una ruta del archivo Py, además que no la tienes creada y a su vez la plantilla HTML.

Crea a ruta así:

```
@route.app('/pagina2/')
def pagina2():
  return render_template('pagina2.html')
```

Además de esto debe importa render_template, y tener en la carpeta templates la plantilla pagina2.html

de igual forma en el HTML quedaría el input así:

```
<input class="boton" type="submit" value="JUGAR" name="jugar" onclick='/Pagina2/'>
```

NOTA: te recomiendo leer un poco mas de jinja2 y flask.

Answer (score 0):

`url_for` llama al html de la carpeta templates en el archivo python como el ejemplo del final en flask, y en el input del html se llama con la sintaxis de del ejemplo de abajo. Esta sintaxis se debe a que no es un html puro, porque es procesado por el motor de jinja.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Monopoly Online.</title>
        <meta charset = "uft-8">
        <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="/static/CSS/estilos.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img style="width: 1100px;" class="logo1" src="/static/Imagenes/Logo%20Monopoly1.png">

        <input class="boton" type="submit" value="JUGAR" name="jugar" href="{{url_for('Pagina2')}}">

        <p>Creado por KESTOC </p>

    </body>
</html>
<p>
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, render_template, flash, session

import sys

import flask

from flask import json

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_envvar('FLASKR_SETTINGS', silent=True)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def inicio():
    """
    """
    error = None
    return render_template('Inicio_monopoly.html', error=error)


@app.route("/pagina2")

def pagina2():
    return render_template("Pagina2.html")

if __name__ == "'__main__'":
    app.run()
</p>
```